# Discovered: Run A Video In An Image

Tags: windows, image, media-player, printscreen

okay i have found the way to run a video in a image.... the procedure as given below

1 - Run a video in Windows Media Player

2 - While the video running, Press Print Screen

3 - Paste it in MS Paint

4 - Save the image in JPEG or BMP format

5 - Run any video in Windows Media Player again

6 - Now open that image, in Windows Page\Fax Viewer or ACDsee etc.

7 - at this time the win. media player is playing and the image is open

8- Switch to image (focus on image) and you will see the currently running video in the image

can anybody with extensive knowledge of windows tell me why does this happen.

Well this doesn't work in all versions of windows and media players. i tried this on the follwing setup

Windows Media Player 10

Windows XP 2006 SP2

Comment: Did you try it with other images than the screenshot? I can't imagine that there's a relation between the screenshot and the video. Would love to try it, but I'm on a mac. But I would be very interested in an explanation to this myself.

Comment: This isn't a question.  I suspect you're seeing some sort of artifact because the video player is overlaying the video on top of everything else.

Comment: @Jason: no its not overlaying.. once you try it you will know probably there's something going on...

@Andre: then why don't you vote it up ;)

Comment: @Jason: He's curious about the implementation/underlying technology of the windows media player and windows. Why shouldn't this qualify as a real question. I agree that it's not a "How do I .." or "Why isn't this working"-question, but I still think that curiosity is very important and should be supported and not discouraged.

Comment: Windows Media Player is running the video using the Windows Overlay buffer which does not use normal screen memory.  It is a feature of your video card.

Comment: The Print Screen key can not capture images from the video card's overlay buffer.

Comment: @BoltBait: yes but What does it pastes in MS Paint or saves in JPEG (lempel Ziv-W format) and the BMP (run length enconding format) that when ever a video is being played it also show in the image. 

@Andre: hey thanks for the vote n support....

Comment: i forgot to mention if you play the video and see the pasted image in mspaint, even in mspaint it runs the video then you can draw on  it and what you draw will be there in the image but the undrew area will still display the video ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give a concise answer rather than a comment:
This behavior depends both on the player you are using and on your graphics card. What happens is the following:

1. The video player fills its video window with a single, flat color. Usually, this will either be a bright pink or something close to, but not exactly, black. The idea is to choose a color that is not likely to appear anywhere else on screen.
2. The video player instructs the acceleration chip on your graphics card to play back the video, but to display it only on parts of the screen that have that exact color. To achieve this, a technique called "overlay" is used, which effectively allows the graphics card to "overlay" video content on any part of the screen that is filled with this particular color.

Now, if you took a screenshot of the player while it way playing, what you have is an image that contains a large uniform fill where the video is supposed to be. If you display this screenshot while playing the video, the graphics card will not be able to tell the difference between the solid color within the player and a screenshot of it. It will just replace this color with the video.

You can have fun with this behavior by drawing onto the screenshot. Whatever you drew will appear to be drawn on top of the video, because the video only shows wherever the screen has the exact color used by the video player.